# Away3d aplying texture/ matterial issues

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textures, away3d

Hello i try to texture a sphere with a png but it apply the texture wrong and messes it up.
i cant find any way to move it around and play with the texture/material untill it will be set correctly.
i want to create a soccer ball and to apply it a ball texture
This is my code i use to create the material and apply it
Thanks

```
[Embed(source=”../assets/Ball.png”)]
public static var TheBallTextureClass:Class;
public var TheBallMaterial:TextureMaterial;

var theball:Mesh;

TheBallTexture = new BitmapTexture(new TheBallTextureClass().bitmapData);
TheBallMaterial = new TextureMaterial(Cast.bitmapTexture(TheBallTexture));
TheBallMaterial.smooth = true;
TheBallMaterial.repeat = true;

theball = new Mesh(new SphereGeometry(30), _ballMaterial);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the UV Mapping of the SphereGeometry is weird and is not made for a pattern like the soccer ball.

I suggest you to create the sphere in 3ds max and unwrap it there.

EDIT:
If you want you can edit UV mapping of SphereGeometry inside Away3D:

Create a SubClass of SphereGeometry and override "buildUVs(target:CompactSubGeometry)" creating your own set of UVs.

Comment: Thanks, wierd, there is no way to manipulate the png on the sphere?

Comment: No, but you can manipulate the UV coordinates even if i don't reccomend it because it's a mess

Comment: Sorry, im new to away3d how can i manipulate the UV on where should i do it? On the mesh? on the material or on the geometry?